# HTML Controls visible property in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a span element in my asp.net page without runat server attribute. I need to set this span's visibility, but the decision to make it visible has to come from code behind. I don't want to set runat="server"

Comment: where is your backend code execute? in client? if not how you gona do this without putting runat="server"? I think you shoud use javascript mate

Comment: No i will be using javascript only but how to tell javascript that we need to hide the span element or rather how do we tell javascript to do so

Comment: Allow me to reword this question:  Hi guys, I want to be able to control visibility for a control in the code behind but I don't want to have add runat="server" to the control so that it can be "seen" from the code behind.  Is there a way I can do this (more lines of code, the better) without adding 14 characters to my span tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this in your code behind, I am using jQuery but no need to really.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>$('#MySpan').fadeOut('slow');</SCRIPT>");
```

Update:

You can read an variable from the server to see if you want to render the span or not while rendering the page. jQuery Code.. ShowMySpan is an public int variable on the server

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (<%: ShowMySpan %> == 0) {
            $("#MySpan").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }          
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply that is what i will do after i have come to know to hide it first i need to to know in jquey to hide the element

Answer (score 0):

This will probably help you [Using JavaScript Along with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx). Here you will be better to go through [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx).

I think the way `StefanE` done will work. Will be easy if you use `class` instead of `ID` since the `ID` may be changed during runtime. Also it will be better to use [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
so you can do something like `$('.MySpan').hide()`